# Typedef struct errors when attempting to initialize member(s)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, typedef

I know the code below is not complete. I'm debugging it as I go and no matter what I do, I can't figure out why I get error: request for member 'gpa' in something not a structure or union (line 22). I'm positive there is more to be done with the code and that there are more warnings and errors, I'm not worried about those yet. Just this one I have never encountered before.

```
#define     _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#define     MAXNAME        11
#define     MAXSTUDENTS     9


typedef struct student
    {
        char    name[ MAXNAME ];
        double  gpa;
        char    grade;
    }student_t;

void    grade_students(student_t  *, int n);
void    print_students(student_t  *, int n);

int main()
{
    student_t   students[ MAXSTUDENTS ];
    int         n;
    students.gpa    =   n;
    FILE        *infilep;

    infilep = fopen("lab09.in", "r");

}
```

What I am trying to do is use the typedef members but when I try to follow the format used in my text and classnotes, I get the error.

Comment: `n` is uninitialized, so to what exactly you are trying to initialize `gpa`? Also, `students` is an array, not a struct.

Comment: `students` is an array. So the assignment `students.gpa    =   n;` is not valid. You would assign an *element* of the array. For example, `students[0].gpa    =  4.0; //assigns the first element's "gpa".`

Comment: Gotcha @BlueMoon, so for every student I have, I have to enter the students[x student number].gpa = y gpa value. Or is there a faster way to do this? Like a loop to run through a list of values quickly or do I have to assign them all seperately? I got an error saying: expected expression before ']'@Eugene, the error popped up whenever I tried to use a member of the strut. I just used n for example's sake.

Comment: @Tommy Buzaki Have you read my answer?

Comment: @Tommy Buzaki Rather than worry about "a faster way", suggest simply starting with any way that clearly meets your functional needs.  Save optimizations for later.  To begin,use `student_t   students[MAXSTUDENTS] = {0};` to zero fill `students`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `students` is declared as an array of elements of type `student_t`

```
student_t   students[ MAXSTUDENTS ];
```

So to access an element of the array you should use the subscript operator as for example

```
students[0].gpa    =   0.0;
```

Another example can be used in function `print_students`. Though in the function it is just a pointer nevertheless you can use the same syntax with the subscript operator

```
void    print_students( const student_t  *students, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        puts( students[i].name );
        //...
    }
}
```